# What is the difference between "heading to" and "heading for"?

Tags: differences, prepositions, to-for

What is the difference between *to* and *for* in the following statements?

> - I am headed to the airport.
> - I am headed for the airport.

Comment: No difference to speak of.

Comment: Related: _[Should we worry about what precedes a preposition?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/54901/5822)_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference between heading *to* and heading *for* is subtle enough that you can use them interchangeably, yet I think there is a difference.

If you are heading *to* somewhere, you have a strong expectation of getting there promptly.

If you are heading *for* somewhere, you are going in that route, but there is some possibility of not reaching it, or making of stops along the way. An even less definite phrase is *heading towards*.

For example, imagine I was having a night on the town and a friend phoned to find out where I am. If I said:

> "I'm at the bottom of town now, but I am *heading to* the top of town."

... then my friend would probably infer that he should meet me in a pub at the top of town. If I instead said:

> "I'm at the bottom of town now, but I am *heading for* the top of town."

... then my friend is more likely to infer that he should meet me in some pub along that route.

There is an equally subtle difference between *heading* and *headed*. Once more, you *can* use them interchangeably, but *heading* is more active, and *headed* is more passive.

If you are the driver of a vehicle, or walking or running, you would be more likely to say *heading*.

If you are a passenger in a vehicle, or you're walking or running but you're following a leader rather than navigating yourself, you would be more likely to say *headed*.

Answer (score 7):

Native speakers are unlikely to say either. What you might hear is *I’m heading for the airport now.*

Comment: What is the difference between "I am headed for" and "I am heading for"?

Comment: @Mohammad: No difference in meaning, but they'll be used on different occasions. In most normal circumstances, 'heading for' is what you'll find. 'Headed' has a more technical sound to it, and might be heard more perhaps in a navigational environment. It's often difficult to understand such differences by considering the expressions in isolation. You need to hear or see them in context.

Comment: I'd say people are usually *heading for* x, while vehicles are *headed for x* (perhaps it was historically passive in the sense "directed towards", as in "the ship was headed towards the island by her captain"?). And something that is headed for a certain destination probably cannot as easily change course as a human being heading for the same destination.

Comment: I think *heading* is active, while *headed* is passive. If you are driving or walking, you are heading. If you are a passenger in a taxi, bus, boat etc. you are headed. But the question isn't asking this.

Answer (score 5):

Heading to somewhere is deliberate. It denotes an intended destination.

> The plane is heading to Dubai.

Heading for somewhere is not always deliberate, and denotes a direction rather than a destination.

> Oh, no! The plane is heading for those mountains!

You can also use "for" with the intended destination...

> The plane is heading for Dubai.

...however, you can't always tell whether that really is the destination if you do that.

> The plane is heading for Dubai at the moment, and will turn towards Cairo once it clears the English Channel.

Lots of people have given similar answers. Hopefully these examples illustrate the point in a way which clarifies any confusion.

Comment: Are you diametrically on the other side to my view? :)

Comment: I merely provide examples and let them do the talking. It's possible though :)

Answer (score 1):

There indeed seems a difference brought about by the preposition's meaning.

> I am headed **to** the airport.

towards/ in the direction of -- not necessarily terminating at, [the airport]
When I am headed **to** the airport, I am proceeding in the direction of the airport. That I will eventually reach there is merely incidental, and not the import of my statement.

> I am headed **for** the airport.

destined -- not necessarily in the direct way, to [the airport]
When I am headed **for** the airport, my objective is to reach the airport, my *heading* (orientation/ direction) not being the import of the statement. I might take a slightly circuitous route.

Comment: I like your explanation ; )

Comment: Odd, I think the difference is more or less the same, but the opposite way around. See my answer.

Comment: The preposition you would use to mean you were headed in the direction of the airport is *toward(s)*.

Comment: @slim, I noticed the same.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, I meant the use of *to* suggests *toward(s)*.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some minor difference between the both.

But in most of the scenarios "I am headed to the airport" is the proper sign of good usage.

Comment: What do you think are the minor differences?