# What is the right preposition after "skeptical"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is suitable  to follow *skeptical*?

Comment: There are many: He is remains skeptical *about* ... He is skeptical *of* ... He describes himself as skeptical *in* several of his films.  He only said he was skeptical *under* duress... Without refinement I don't think this question can have a meaningful answer.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54901/should-we-worry-about-what-precedes-a-preposition

Comment: I always argued that the preposition depends strongly on what **follows** it, even more than what precedes.

Comment: @Jim The first part is right. The examples, though, do not fit.

Comment: @Kris- I purposely chose  those examples because OP did not constrain his question.  Are they prepositions and do they follow *skeptical*? I agree that they do not all conform to the same model.

Comment: Nice illustrations to show different cohesiveness patterns.

Answer (score 10):

[COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=32726742) finds these frequencies for prepositions that immediately follow *skeptical*:

| Count | Preposition |
| --- | --- |
| 1099 | of |
| 804 | about |
| 21 | as |
| 15 | on |
| 14 | in |
| 11 | at |
| 9 | with |
| 8 | from |
| 6 | to |
| 6 | because |
| 5 | after |
| 4 | by |
| 3 | among |
| 3 | for |
| 3 | toward |
| 2 | without |
| 2 | towards |
| 1 | up |
| 1 | until |
| 1 | like |
| 1 | throughout |
| 1 | through |
| 1 | regarding |
| 1 | over |
| 1 | during |
| 1 | despite |
| 1 | across |
| **2025** | **Total** |

So almost always the right answer is either of *skeptical **of*** or *skeptical **about***, but other possibilities may exist depending on the broader context and personal predilections.  Most of the others are false hits, and not actually part of the *skeptical PREP THING*  bit at all.

I say “personal predilections” because I cannot see myself ever being *skeptical **at*** something, but apparently some people on occasion are so. One of those citations is this one, from a piece of short fiction named “School Days” by Russell Banks in 1995:

> I told him how I’d agreed to send Rose back to her mom in the morning and he looked a little skeptical at that with one eyebrow cocked and his lips pressed together and didn’t say anything one way or the other.

Comment: Why were the other prepositions used *at all?* Because they were needed in view of what follows the preposition, the context, the semantics, more than what precedes? All the above cases must be grammatical and make adequate sense. *Of* may be statistically predominant but eminently unsuitable in a given context.

Comment: @Kris I already answered your question when I explained that those others were almost always false hits that do not describe being skeptical PREP something. Since I already answered your question, that means you’re just quibbling, and I look forward with great relish to reading your own studied answer to the OP.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54901/should-we-worry-about-what-precedes-a-preposition

Answer (score -2):

You pose two different uses of the word and thought.  In the one case a speaker is skeptical "of" a "truth" and in the later he is "posing" (in) skepticism as a position.

One who is skeptical of a "truth" is in fact doubtful of its authenticity.

One who poses as a skeptic writes regarding his belief in the inaccuracy of the given "truth."